# Is the Piggyback guide to Assassin's Creed 3 usable on Wii U version?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, wii-u

I have the Assassin's Creed 3 for Wii U, and I want to buy the Piggyback guide to the game, but in the guide web says it's for PC, PS3 and Xbox360 versions.

I know that Wii U version was launch time after the guide, so.

Can't I use the same guide for the Wii U version of the game?

Comment: I would say yes but IDK if there's any special things you can do with the wii u tablet controller.

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks, I'm more interested if the content, places and so are the same.

Comment: Its exactly the same game minus a few additional missions that might exist which are all similar to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WiiU version is the direct port of the other Assassin Creed versions so the Piggyback guide would be the same.

Here are a few sources confirming this:

> http://wiiudaily.com/2012/10/assassins-creed-3-on-wii-u-is-the-same-as-other-versions/
>
> http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/assassins-creed-iii-for-the-wii-u-same-taste-less-filling/
>
> http://www.nintendolife.com/games/wiiu/assassins_creed_iii